# I would like to pass data from a table with several columns to another table in a single column

Tags: mysql, heidisql

good afternoon / night, let me tell you, I have a database with several tables and one of them is obsolete since I am trying to pass it to another.
I put you in situation.
I have the user_accounts table
with the following format. "image below"

[image: SQL FORMAT 1]

I would like to know if that information can be selected and inserted into another table "users" with this format. "link below"

[image: SQL FORMAT 2]

It would be a search for the identifier and the same update for the identifier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSON is horribly difficult to work with in MySQL. Why do you want to convert to that format?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You have no value after `"money":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JSON_OBJECTAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg)

```
UPDATE users AS u
JOIN (
    SELECT identifier, JSON_OBJECTAGG(name, money) AS accounts
    FROM user_accounts
    GROUP BY identifier
) AS a ON u.identifier = a.identifier
SET u.accounts = a.accounts
```